# ACE acceptor - My_Svc_Handler class

Tags: sockets, ace, reactor

I am using the ace acceptor to listen to a TCP port.
my class inherets from My_Svc_Handler and impliments the funcion int open (void *) of the class My_Svc_Handler.
In all the examples I saw, inside the open function, they registor the reactor:

```
 ACE_Reactor::instance()->register_handler(this, 
     ACE_Event_Handler::READ_MASK);
```

I dont understant why do we need to registore? I already have a reactore waiting for an event. This I defined in main:

```
typedef ACE_Acceptor<My_Svc_Handler,ACE_LSOCK_ACCEPTOR> MyAcceptor;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ 
 ACE_UNIX_Addr addr("/tmp/addr.ace"); 
 MyAcceptor acceptor(address, ACE_Reactor::instance());

while(1) /* Start the reactors event loop */ 
  ACE_Reactor::instance()->handle_events(); 
}
```

I guess I dont understand when is the open function called.

I have another question on that manner. Is there another way in the main not running the while(1) ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to register is because the default implementation of the `Reactor` in ACE on UNIX/Linux is `Select_Reactor` and as the name implies all this reactor is doing is running a `select` system call which dispatches events when the data is available on the socket.  So unless you tell `select` to add the socket to the list of sockets in the `select`s reading or writing descriptor lists `Reactor` won't do anything when data is present on the socket.

That's what `register_handler` is for.